# Pattern matching difference between java and android?

Tags: java, android, regex

funny enough (or not) in java the match var evaluates to true, but in android it does not:

```
CharSequence target = "man on";
boolean match = ​target.toString().matches("(\\p{L}\\p{L}+-?\\s?\\p{L}+)+");
```

Any idea why this happens?

thanks.

PS: I got it working by importing and using Matcher.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\p{L}\\p{L}+-?\\s?\\p{L}+)+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(target);
```

and then matcher.matches() evaluates to true on "man on".

Comment: Why do you call `toString` on a `String`?

Comment: Must be something about the way android implements `String.matches`, because you have basically just inlined the way that `String.matches` works in the second case (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#2101)

Comment: @fabian: sorry, I pasted the code here and poorly edited it. In the android app there is no 
`String target = "man on"` 
target is actually a CharSequence.. :)

Actually I just tested it and the second works for "man on" but not "man on moon". Which should be the case due to the ()+ or? 
And of course on browxy.com 
`boolean bla = args[0].toString().matches("(\\p{L}\\p{L}+-?\\s?\\p{L}+)+");` 
works even for "man on the moon bla fish"..

Comment: Seems that your `CharSequence` incorrectly implements `toString()`. `Pattern.matcher()` may accept `CharSequence` argument, in which, I believe, it searches for matches using `charAt()`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, yep, once I changed to Pattern/Matcher I dropped the toString() as the matcher() accepts CharSequence. I just tested and there is no difference in using toString() or not, "man on" evaluates to true and anything with a second space (i.e. "man on moon") evaluates to false.

Comment: @cristian so problem is solved? Anyway, try to log what `target.toString()` actually returns. I expect to see something like `TextHelperImpl@d32f594`

Comment: no actually not. As I've said it works for "man on" (just one space) but not "man on moon" or "man on the moon" (more than 1 space). 
target.toString() prints out the string itself like "man on". `I/System.out: man on`

Also testing on [link](www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) even "\p{L}\p{L}+(\\s|-|\\s-|-\\s)?\p{L}*" should match "man on the". odd.

Comment: so the issue with multiple spaces was the regex pattern. Using `^[\p{L}\s.-]+\p{L}$` is ok. 

Still don't understand the behavior difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is in incorrect implementation of `CharSequence` methods, or absense of overriden `toString()` in actual class of `target`.

`Pattern#matcher(target)` accepts `CharSequence`, `String#matches()` operates on `String`. Result may be different if `target.toString()` returns string that is not equal to actual contents of `target`.